# mysqli_affected_rows in PHP insert

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have this code:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    $insert_member_sql = "INSERT INTO members (id, username) VALUES('$id', '$username')";
    $insert_member_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_member_sql);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($con, $insert_member_res)>0){
    echo "1";
    }else{
    echo "0";
    }
};
```

All is working fine with the sending of an email and inserting the information to a database but the mysqli_affected_rows isn't working - How can I edit this code to echo 1 after running the query?

Comment: Read [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con, $insert_member_res)>0)
```

to

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0)
```

`mysqli_affected_rows` only requires `connection link` object but you passed query object also that was the problem

Answer (score 2):

or you can echo it

```
echo mysqli_affected_rows($con);
```

in case you want to double check of course

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    $insert_member_sql = "INSERT INTO members (id, username) VALUES('$id', '$username')";

    if (!mysql_query($insert_member_sql) ){
    echo "1";
    }else{
    echo "0";
    }
};
```