# Can you use if else statements while inserting data into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now.  I've looked online and can't seem to find anything on this specific topic.  Any help would be great.

The form is using a plugin on Wordpress called Ninja Forms.  I cannot see the output of the form or get errors because the form is a plugin.  I have looked at the code on the plugin, but I can't make heads and tails of it.  So, the purpose of this question is to see if I've at least written my code correctly.  It isn't working.  That means either I have a mistake here or I'm going to have to find a way to decrypt part of this plugin and reverse engineer it to see how it works and why this code isn't working.   My hope is I've screwed up here.  Particularly on using the IF ELSE Statement.

With that being said, I have a database where you can store a lead or a customer.   Instead of having two tables, I want them in the same table.  So on the form - you choose "customer" or "lead" and then it shows the next appropriate field to put in the business name.  It should go in the database as:

customer
chickens Inc.

or

lead
chickens Inc.

Here is the code I've made.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass!1";
$dbname = "data";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//Look at what type of data we are getting and then set the correct variables.
if ($_POST['type'] == "customer") {
    $datatype = $_POST['type'];
    $company = $_POST['company_name'];
} else {
    $datatype = $_POST['type'];
    $company = $_POST['lead_name'];
}
//Process the SQL Statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (datatype, company)
VALUES ('$datatype', '$company')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: code seems correct.. But What issue you are facing ?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Aside from [SQL injection flaws](https://xkcd.com/327/), what's the problem? what's the error?

Comment: beware of sql injection in that code...you're doing at least that wrong :)

Comment: maybe be you can throw away the quotes in your query   `$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (datatype, company) VALUES ($datatype, $company)"` on the same line, otherwise  concatenate $sql .= "values..." and terminate the line above correctly

Comment: @scraaappy No, that's even worse. These are strings here ;-)

Comment: I'm going to change it all over using transactions and stuff - but I just want to get a framework to see if it works.  I can't use the error reporting.  I am using this with Ninja Forms on wordpress and it sends a webhook to this file.  But you guys say this would work...so maybe the "value" isn't being set to what I think it is?   The issue is nothing is going in the database.  But before the if statement - it worked (using the first variable set.)

Comment: @sherwood; post your HTML form. If not, then make sure your form is using a POST method and that all your inputs have name attributes and with no typos/lettercase issues. Error reporting will tell you that. Far as I'm concerned, your posted code looks kosher to me.

Comment: Can do this too: `$datatype = $_POST['type']; $company = array_key_exists("company_name", $_POST)?$_POST['company_name']:$_POST['lead_name'];`

Comment: can't use error reporting; oh, lovely. why? just echo them on screen like I posted. Otherwise, you'll need to figure it out if you're not going to take any of our/my suggestions. Use `isset()` and or `empty()`. Good luck.

Comment: I can't use error reporting because it is being sent by a form on wordpress and uses a webhook.  So this file isn't being seen by the browser.  The browser stays on the same page using ajax to submit the form. 

But, you guys say this works.  So, I'll go with that and see if something is being screwed up elsewhere.

Comment: show us your HTML form and the whole kit then. if that's irrelevant, then we can't help you.

Comment: I asked if the code worked.  You guys said yes.  So, you have helped.  I don't want the complete answer if it is elsewhere - I won't learn as well that way.  I just wanted to make sure what i have works at least on this side.   Thanks.  : )

Comment: @maalls that isn't necessarily true. Using `mysqli_affected_rows()` will.

Comment: yeah as I said, checking if query return true on insert is how to do it isn't it ?

Comment: @maalls query will return true regardless if there are no errors. If there was a UNIQUE constraint on any given column, then that will return an error.

Comment: @fred not sure to follow you...anyway, seems like the code is actually working which is not a surprise for me.

Comment: I'm not keeping the oranges.  I'm more interested in the cherries.  In truth, I don't know how to show the HTML because the form is a plugin for wordpress.  I create an ajax form and then use a shortcode to display it on a page.  The code I've written is to catch that information and store it.

Comment: sorry I didn't look into detail but you are using update, not insert.

Comment: Your question is unclear, off-topic and also falls into "why it's not working". We're not fortune tellers, or mind readers; we're "code" readers. If you can't copy/paste code, then answers given below, will be guesswork at best. Now, where's my coffee and danish?

Comment: @maalls It doesn't matter; the principal is the same. I only pasted a script I had kicking around here. I wasn't going to make up a whole new script - wink.

Comment: it's a bit different actually, update wont return any errors if no row are changed. insert will return an error if the row(s) can't be added.

Comment: @maalls yeah, true on that point. Although, it would return an error if there was a UNIQUE constraint on trying to enter the same data.

Comment: yep, that's what I mean by "if the row(s) can't be added".

Comment: @maalls OP's question's stale/dead, far as I'm concerned. An answer was posted below, and it's still going nowhere *fast*. Good luck to them. Enjoy your day/evening ;-) *Cheers & ciao*

Comment: OP question deserves -1 because the code actually works and he said afterward he just wanted SO to confirm it's working or not instead of checking by himself. I will enjoy my evening (Tokyo), thanks !

Comment: I disagree on the -1s.  My question explicitly asks:  "Here is the code I've made. Am I doing something wrong?"  The subject is the code and the question is absolutely about the subject.  Not the form - but the code I supplied.  I have worked on this for a good portion of today and couldn't get it to work.  BEFORE I dug into all the code of the WP plugin, it made more sense to make sure that you could set variables using an if else statement when inserting into mysql.  That is what I asked.  The answer is yes.  Now I know the problem is elsewhere which means I can spend time digging into that.

Comment: And after digging - if I can't figure something out regarding THAT - I'll ask.    In other words - before I dig into this plugin's code, I'm going to make sure this part at least works and isn't the problem.  That way I won't waste my time for nothing.

Comment: @maalls *Ah,* a very good point. +1 on that comment. Very beautiful in Tokyo.

Comment: @malls Update on `mysqli_affected_rows()` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15568966/ and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.affected-rows.html *Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.* - so it does work with INSERT after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that if you use a single dropdown [type] and single text input [variable name?] in your html to select type and capture the business name that you'd be using two different variable names for the business name in the backend.

e.g. you have both

```
$company = $_POST['company_name'];
```

and

```
$company = $_POST['lead_name'];
```

by your description of the form, the variable passing the business name would be the same unless you're adjusting that on the fly which would be counter to the simplified approach you're going for.

FYI, you can send your error reporting to a file instead displaying it, which will work fine in wordpress.

Comment: How would I send the error to another file?   Eventually, this will have business name, address1, address2, state, zip, phone, etc.  The form asks if they want to create a lead or customer and then AJAX is used to show the fields they need for that.  But, I guess you're right.  All of those fields could be the same regardless since the type (Lead or Customer) differentiates it..

Comment: Read up on error reporting in PHP, you can set your errors to be reported to a serverside log file which you can view after the code runs.